# C# - how to find the enabled textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a small program with some textboxes. Exactly one of these textboxes will always be enabled. Using C#, how can I find the enabled checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be working very well

```
for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
            {
                var enabledbox = this.Controls.Find("textbox" + i, true);
                foreach (TextBox enabledbox1 in enabledbox)
                {
                    if (enabledbox1.Enabled == true)
                    {
                        //do something
                    }
                }
            }
```